# Definition of standard deviation, matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics

I have  a matrix

tst=[20    15    26    32    18    28    35    14    26    22    17]

meantst= mean(tst)=23

stdtst= std(tst)=6.6

Matlab command

```
s = std(X)
```

one get standard deviation.

http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/std.html

How can I get  std with 1-sigma(68%), 2 sigma(95%), 3sigma(99%)".

Comment: What do you mean? The numbers 68,95,99 you have written, they mean that in a Gaussian distribution, 68% of the values lie in the range of plus or minus sigma. That is in your case, if the `tst` followed Gaussian distribution, then 68% of the values would lie in the range of [23-6.6] to [23+6.6] i.e. from 16.4 to 29.6

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not actually looking for the standarddeviation, but rather the quantiles of your distribution.

Assuming they are normally distributed, you could go for [`norminv`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/stats/norminv.html):

```
X = norminv(P,mu,sigma)
```

Comment: How can I get normalised form of my data. Is P=(tst-meantst)/stdtst.

Comment: @user31177 Try `help norminv` or `doc norminv` to find out what the inputs are.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular examples says that 68 percent of data present between 16.4 to 29.6. If you consider 2Sigma, Then 95% of data present between 9.8 to 35.5. Standard deviation just tells, how much data is deviating from its mean value. If just consider standard deviation then standard deviation gives a range around mean, and in that range 68% of data exist. If we take 2Sigma, we increase that range twice and now 95% of  data fall in that range.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is the *percentiles* of the distribution?

```
prctile(tst,68) % or prctile(tst,100-68), depending on which direction you need
prctile(tst,95) % or prctile(tst,100-95)
prctile(tst,99) % or prctile(tst,100-99)
```

Note that you would need many more samples than your example contains in order to obtain accurate percentile values.